# Дублирование записи Symfony 4 с новым id

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, symfony

Вопрос по Symfony 4, можно и ниже. В общем ломаю голову как сделать чтоб по нажатию кнопки появлялась такая же запись только с другим айди, ++ от максимального к примеру[image: пример записи]

По нажатию на желтую кнопку copy ниже появляется такая же запись только id равен 2
через запросы? тогда как правильно передать переменную которая хранит id записи для ее копирования? для, к примеру, удаления есть такой роутинг `@Route("/{id}", name="pack_delete", methods="DELETE")`

Вот такой Вариант не работает как подсказали ниже, мне кажется что за место remove в $em->remove($ability); нужно использовать что-то другое, удаление тоже не помогло

```
/**
 * @Route("/copy/{id}", name="ability_copy", methods="GET|POST")
 */
public function copy(Request $request, Ability $ability): Response
{
    if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('copy'.$ability->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($ability);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('ability_index');
}
```

Comment: Как-то так `@Route("/copy/{id}", name="pack_copy", methods="POST")` Контроллер подхватывает `id`, находит его в бд и копирует данные.

Comment: к сожалению не сработало, выше добавил понятный код как я сделал,вот тут есть строка $em->remove($ability); мне кажется лишняя, и удаление ее ничего не меняет, может что-то другое вписать нужно

Comment: `remove` удаляет запись. Вам же надо скопировать имеющуюся. То есть найти сущность с нужным ИД, клонировать ее и сохранить. Если у вас сразу в контроллер попадает нужная `$ability` то это еще меньше проблем.

Comment: Так как у вас доктрина, то поиск `Doctrine clone entity` чего нибудь да покажет.

Comment: Ничего не нагуглилось, неужели я один такой кому понадобилась такая функция?

Comment: Прямо первый результат из гугла https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071094/how-to-re-save-the-entity-as-another-row-in-doctrine-2

Comment: Большое спасибо, это все потому что я не умею гуглить на английском языке, решение действительно аккуратное, как исполню в таком виде обязательно добавлю в ответы, спасибо еще раз мудрейший =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил все самым наверно костыльным способом, прошу, если кто-то знает способ красивей опишите ниже
Мой вариант с коментариями

***AbilityController.php***

```
/**
     * @Route("/copy/{id}", name="ability_copy", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    public function copy(Request $request, Ability $ability): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //получение entityManager"ера
        $connection = $entityManager->getConnection(); //получение коннекшина к дефолтной базе данных
        $copingId = $ability->getId(); //получние {id} из роутинга
        $mappings = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getClassMetadata(Ability::class);
        $fieldNames = $mappings->getFieldNames(); //получаем массив названий столбцов
        array_shift($fieldNames); //удаляет первый элемент массива [0]=> int(1) "id" 
        $valuesString = implode("`,`", $fieldNames);//из массива получаем строку вида idItem','code','reloadTime','durationTime','idAbilityType','dateCreated','author','dateChange','lastAuthor
        $sqlAddEntry = "INSERT INTO Ability (`".$valuesString."`) SELECT `".$valuesString."` FROM Ability WHERE id = $copingId;"; //INSERT INTO Ability (`code`...) SELECT `code`... FROM Ability WHERE id = 1;
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($sqlAddEntry);   //готовим сформированный запрос
        $stmt->execute();                       //выполняем запрос
        return $this->redirectToRoute('ability_index');
    }
```

***index.html.twig***

```
<a class="dublicate-btn" href="{{ path('ability_copy', {'id': ability.id}) }}">Копировать запись</a>
```